# error when comparing conditions with data retrieved from tag values ​in HTML and JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I followed online learning, while learning about JSON using javascript, I got an error in one of the conditions in my program. I have tried to debug where the results of my porgram should be "Yes". but that did not happen. please help me resolve this error.

```js
$('.nav-link').on('click', function() {
  $('.nav-link').removeClass('active');
  $(this).addClass('active');

  let kategori = $(this).html();
  $('#headermenu').html(kategori);

  $.getJSON('data/pizza.json', function(data) {
    let menu = data.menu;
    let content = '';

    $.each(menu, function(i, data) {
      console.log('kategori = ' + data.kategori + '->' + kategori.toLowerCase());
      jkategori = data.kategori;
      pkategori = kategori.toLowerCase();
      if (jkategori == String(pkategori)) {
        console.log('Yes');
      } else {
        console.log('No');
      }
      // console.log(content);
    });
    $('#daftar-menu').html(content);
  });
});
```

17/5000
console log results :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yUogP.png)

Comment: What is the error you get???

Comment: there is no error, but the statement that comes out should be some "Yes", for example the value that I got from html = "pizza" and the data that is on my json there is also pizza in it. but the results of the log nothing "YES".

Comment: in the picture that I uploaded if the result is pizza-> pizza then the writing below it should be Yes.

Comment: Log `jkategori, pkategori` before the condition, make sure they've equal length too. I they don't, use `trim()` to remove the extra space from the values.

Comment: solved, much thank brother